# Is there a way to ENABLE the scroll bounce in a trigger.io app?

Tags: jquery-mobile, trigger.io

I'm using jquerymobile and trigger.io to create an IOS app. In my listview if I scroll up and down I don't get the familiar BOUNCE effect? Is this disabled in trigger.io apps? Can it be turned on?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK I don't think there is a way to simply 'turn it on'. You may need to look at a javascript work-around such as Cubiq.org's iScroll4 http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4